# How ajax will GET the data from the golang code?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, go

I have a golang API for saving and retrieving the data from the form. Saving the data filled in the HTML form is okay. Means it will save the data in  database of mongodb successfully but in case of retrieving the data it will retrieve the data on the basis of the email filled in the field of the html form is successful but it shows the data in the terminal of the ubuntu. Below is the code I'm trying for this:-

Html form index.html file

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input id= "firstname" type="text" name="FirstName"  placeholder="Enter your firstname"><br><br>
    <input id= "lastname" type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Enter your lastname"><br><br>
    <input id= "email" type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Enter your email"><br><br>
    <input id= "mobile" type="text" name="Mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile"><br><br>
    <button id= "button1" class="button" name="button" type="button" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    <button id= "button2" class="button" name="button" type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Ajax in index.html is :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //IT will save the data 
    $('#button1').on('click', function(e){
        button=this.value;
        console.log(button);
        e.preventDefault();
        if (button === "Submit") {
            var FirstName =$("#firstname").val(),
            LastName =$("#lastname").val(),
            Email =$("#email").val(),
            Mobile =$("#mobile").val();
            console.log(FirstName);
            $.ajax({
                url:"/login",
                type:"POST",
                data: {'button':button, "first":FirstName, "last":LastName, "email":Email, "mobile":Mobile},
                success: function(results) {
                    console.log(results);
                    $('#response').html(results);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    // This will search and I want the result in the success
    $('#button2').on('click', function(e){
        button=this.value;
        console.log(button);
        e.preventDefault();
        var Email =$("#email").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/get-data",
            type: "GET",
            data:{'button':button,"email":Email},
            success: function(results){
                console.log(results)
                $('#response').html(results);
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Main.go file

```
import (
 "fmt"
 "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
 "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
 "html/template"
 "log"
 "net/http"
 "encoding/json"
)
type USER struct {
 FirstName string `json:"FirstName,omitempty"`
 LastName  string `json:"LastName,omitempty"`
 Email     string `json:"Email,omitempty"`
 Mobile    string `json:"Mobile,omitempty"`
}
func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 fmt.Println("method:", r.Method)
 if r.Method == "GET" {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    t.Execute(w, nil)
 } else {
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Println(r.Form)
    if r.Form["button"][0] == "Submit" {
        fmt.Println(r.Form)
        session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/user")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer session.Close()
        session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
        c := session.DB("user").C("profile")
        doc := USER{
            FirstName: r.Form["first"][0],
            LastName:  r.Form["last"][0],
            Email:     r.Form["email"][0],
            Mobile:    r.Form["mobile"][0],
        }
        err = c.Insert(doc)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("FistName:", r.Form["first"][0])
        fmt.Println("LastName:", r.Form["last"][0])
        fmt.Println("Email:", r.Form["email"][0])
        fmt.Println("Mobile:", r.Form["mobile"][0])
    }
 }
}

func AllData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
 fmt.Println("method:", r.Method)
 if r.Method == "GET" {
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Println(r.Form)
     if r.Form["button"][0] == "Search" {
        fmt.Println(r.Form)
        fmt.Println(r.Form["email"][0])
        session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/user")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer session.Close()
        session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
        c := session.DB("user").C("profile")
        result := Users{}
        err = c.Find(bson.M{"email": r.Form["email"][0]}).All(&result)
        fmt.Println(result)
        b, err := json.MarshalIndent(result, "", "  ")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
    }
 }
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
  http.HandleFunc("/get-data", AllData)
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
  }
}
```

What should I do for receiving the data from golang to the ajax `GET` method request click on the button search and result will display in the success function of the ajax. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the response header of `Data` function in json format and write the response of json which can be received in success of `$.ajax`

```
func AllData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method)
    if r.Method == "GET" {
            // your code ....
           b, err := json.MarshalIndent(result, "", "  ")
           if err != nil {
               panic(err)
           }
           fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
           // set header to 'application/json'
           w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
           // write the response
           w.Write(b)
       }
    }
}
```

Also there is an error in your code where you are returning from handler func `AllData` either create a middleware if you wants to do some modification in result or remove the return part of handler `AllData`

Comment: it will giving me a error   `cannot use string(b) (type string) as type []byte in argument to w.Write
./main.go:98:1: missing return at end of function
./main.go:103:18: cannot use AllData (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) Users) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to http.HandleFunc
`

Comment: now it will giving the error of this `cannot use AllData (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) Users) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to http.HandleFunc
`

Comment: yes because your `AllData` is returning `users` thats an error . Please check edited code.

Comment: yes you can. But I am getting late for some where you can drop your query. I will check it

Comment: Why should it giving the error of that i told you? The code you give is alright it works but can you explain it for me what is actually it is doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170203/discussion-between-himanshu-and-gourav).